# Getting error "html2canvas is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm using the latest version of Html2canvas.js here, in the latest Chrome browser, under Linux.

I am getting an error:

```
Error: html2canvas is not a function
```

The error appears whenever I try to use Html2canvas:

```js
exportArea.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  html2canvas(document.querySelector('#tablesArea')).then(canvas => {
    let canvasUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(canvasUrl);
  });
});
```

I presume that I do not really import Html2canvas, although I have written this at the start of my js script, and `html2canvas.js` is in the same folder as the `projname.html` and `projname.js` is.

First line from `projname.js`:

```js
import * as html2canvas from './html2canvas.js';
```

I also wrote this in the html file:

```html
<script type="module" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
```

In order to use the `html2canvas.js` file I had to disable JS source maps and CSS source maps, or Chrome would throw a map related error. If I was using the `.min.js` file, I would not get the map related error, but it seems that I have to use the non-min latest ver of Html2canvas?... Anyway, even if I use the `.min.js` version of the module I still get the `html2canvas is not a function` error.

I am a complete beginner, but I have grinded this problem for a whole day without any result - and Google searches did not provide me with a wealth of info regarding this problem, sadly. I cannot understand why this does not work.

Comment: what you wrote in html file?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started) the input statement should be `import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';`.

Answer (score -1):

When you have these problems with importing, importmaps are a good method to import modules :

```
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
              "html2canvas": <!-- <-- this can be anything you want --> "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.js",
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

in js :

```
import * as html2canvas from "html2canvas" // this should be the name you specified in importmap
```

Importmaps are somehow an import manager which makes it so easier to import modules.
Cdn.js is a website that has almost all the modules of javascript(like jquery or chart.js) and if Cdn.js didnt have the module that you need use jsDelivr which is an another good resource to import javascript module.These link-based modules dont need node.js.
For more information about importmap : [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap)